# Javascript call parent function

Tags: javascript, call, parent

Question inside the description

```
function Parent(){
    this.alertParent(){
        alert("Parent alert");
    }

    function child(){
        // how can I call to this.alertParent() from here without passing any  
        // parameters?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title of your question is confusing. The informal term "parent" function is rather used for the *calling* function.

In your case, you have two functions inside a constructor function and you just want to call one from the other. Specifically, you want to call a "public" method from a "private" method (I put these terms in quotes since JavaScript does not support visibility and these are workaround to achieve the same).

Just keep a reference to the current instance:

```
function Parent(){
    var self = this;
    this.alertParent = function() {
        alert("Parent alert");
    }

    function child() {
        self.alertParent();
    }
}
```

`child` closes over all variables in the context it is defined, so it as access to `self`. [`this` of course changes *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Instead of creating a closure, you can also pass the instance *explicitly* to `child`, using either [`.call()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

So your function definition stays

```
function child() {
    this.alertParent();
}
```

and when you call the function, you call it, e.g. with `child.call(this)` if you know that `this` refers to your instance (instead of `this` it can be any other variable).

Answer (score 3):

Your code has syntax error. Maybe you means this:

```
function Parent(){
    this.alertParent = function () {
        alert("Parent alert");
    };

    this.child = function () {
      this.alertParent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to child to be a parameter, just want t call his rapper function

Comment: What do you mean by child is a parameter?